# print details from from to word document and then print to printer c#

Tags: c#, printing

i am making a holiday booking program my second program. i have a form that client are able to make bookings etc. what i thought of is that i can make like a receipt that would print out all the details on a receipt o designed in photoshop and put it in a word document. so when i click print i am able to print out the receipt through word. my problem im facing is how to get all that information to word so that it can be printed. i went through google but the only way of print i git was that it would print out the form and the information. is there perhaps an other way.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do this thing, use COM automation.  No, it won't be pretty :~(

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx

Comment: lol thanks for reply i will google COM automation. im willing to learn so the uglier the better:)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of which you could look into is by using Word Pragmatically.

You could, for example create a TEMPLATE DOC in word with BOOKMARKS in your word document, you could then write some code to open up a new instance of word,u sing your template doc and select each bookmark and fill it in.

Look at this link as a starting point: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383